# KIA Rio 2015 locked on the 3d gear

Tags: troubleshooting, automatic-transmission, clutch, kia

This is a  KIA Rio 2015 with an automatic transmission . when the lever is on the D position it shifts to the 3d gear directly ( doesn't move until I let the brakes ). using the scanner it showed two codes :

- P0755  Shift Solenoid "B"  ( Active )
- P0743  Torque converter Clutch circuit electrical (Active )

the problem appeared after an transmission oil change. so i changed it again in case it was a bad one and cleared the codes. if i change gears ( move the  lever ) while the ignition ON and engine OFF then start the car I can drive normally (can change to any gear 1,2,3,4 ) and the problem won't come up. but if I start the engine directly puting the lever on D will make the car shift to 3d gear

what should I check ?

I think the transmission name is A4CF2

Comment: Since this is quite a new car, I suspect it is still covered by the warranty. I recommend you demand the dealership to do whatever it takes to fix this problem.